# Dual boot: Windows 10 update leads to ACPI BIOS Error (bug) (November 2019)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, 18.10, bios

I am running GNU GRUB Version 2.02 on my MSI GL62M 7REX which has an intel CORE i7 processor and a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti graphics card.

I am using GNU GRUB Version 2.02 in order to be able to boot (unfortunately outdated) Ubuntu 18.10 or Windows 10 Professional, 64 bit.

Yesterday, Windows 10 did some updates and upgrades whereby it manipulated some BIOS configurations. Today, I wanted to start Ubuntu 18.10 which I wanted to upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10, but it failed to boot. This was my error message:

```
[    0.161284] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could nor resolve [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psargs-330)
[    0.161295] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \SB.PAGD._STA, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-516)
[    0.176456] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could nor resolve [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psargs-330)
[    0.176466] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \SB.PAGD._STA, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-516)
[    0.236992] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could nor resolve [\_SB.PAGD._STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psargs-330)
[    0.237003] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \SB.PAGD._STA, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-516)
[    0.855251] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40000 f80
[    0.855298] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40000 f80
/dev/sda5: clean, 477157/6406144 files, 22860675/25600000 blocks
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "system default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
```

I do not know why it shows the error message three/two times. After that, the following option shows up:

```
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Ctrl+D to continue):
```

If I press `Enter`, I can type `system default` or `exit` but I end up at the same spot. `systemctl reboot` will just reboot the system so that I end up at the same spot again. Pressing `Ctrl+D` does not seem to do anything and ends up throwing me at the very same spot.

I also took a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111056/ubuntu-wont-boot-when-first-booting-with-dual-boot-windows-10) but it did not help me. What can I do?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI, and if SSD, the firmware for the SSD? Is nVidia driver installed.  Is nVidia driver installed? or using nomodeset boot parameter? MSI GS65  Boot parameter: modprobe.blacklist=nouveau 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061109/dual-boot-windows-10-cannot-boot-latest-ubuntu-but-only-older-versions
MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off

Comment: As you can see, I was able to fix the ACPI BIOS Error (bug) and wanted to reinstall the `nvidia-driver-390` after that. Ubuntu, however, cannot connect itself to the internet via Ethernet or WiFi. I have found [this possible solution](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/solved-ethernet-cable-plugged-in-but-no-internet-ubuntu-18-04.3298461/post-20179169) but my BIOS seems to look very different. Do you know what I can do to enable `Secondary LAN` on my computer?

Comment: This is how my BIOS looks like: [Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPx6h.jpg), [Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J68H.jpg), [Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJQv4.jpg), [Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysted.jpg)

Comment: Missed that it was 18.10 which has reached EOL. - end of life. Use a current version of Ubuntu. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the ACPI BIOS Error (bug) by opening the editor when Ubuntu was selected in GNU GRUB Version 2.02 by pressing `e`. There, I removed `acpi_osi=` and the error was gone.

Now, however, [another error occured regarding `systemd`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1187524/841640).